# Configuring Notepad++ to highlight .proj files as XML

Tags: notepad++

Digging around the settings, Google and Super User, I haven't found how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also do this from the UI:

**Settings > Style Configurator**

Select "XML" in the Language list (1) and add "csproj" to the "User ext." field (2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to edit the langs.xml file in Notepad++'s installation directory, which is usually C:\Program Files\Notepad++.  Just find the XML section near the bottom of the file and add "proj" to the list of XML extensions.

Comment: You'll have to use a different editor to do it this way. Notepad++ will overwrite langs.xml on exit. ChrisF's answer is probably the correct way to do it (and the reason langs.xml gets overwritten).